# Terraform - can't reach web server - instance out of service

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm running the below terraform code to deploy an ec2 instance inside a VPC to work as web server but for some reason I cant reach the website and cant shh to it, I have set the ingress and egress rules properly I believe:

```
########Provider########

provider "aws" {
    region      = "us-west-2"
    access_key  = "[redacted]"
    secret_key  = "[redacted]"
}

########VPC########
resource "aws_vpc" "vpc1" {
  cidr_block       = "10.1.0.0/16"
  tags = {
    Name = "Production"
  }
}

########Internet GW########
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "gw" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc1.id
}

########Route table########
resource "aws_route_table" "rt" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc1.id
  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/24"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.gw.id
  }

  route {
    ipv6_cidr_block = "::/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.gw.id
  }

}

########Sub Net########
resource "aws_subnet" "subnet1" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.vpc1.id
  cidr_block = "10.1.0.0/24"
  availability_zone = "us-west-2a"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = "true"

  tags = {
    Name = "prod-subnet-1"
  }
}

########RT assosiation########
resource "aws_route_table_association" "a" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.subnet1.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.rt.id
}

########Security Group########
resource "aws_security_group" "sec1" {
  name        = "allow_web"
  description = "Allow web inbound traffic"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.vpc1.id

  ingress {
    description = "HTTP from VPC"
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["10.1.0.0/16"]
  }

        #SSH access from anywhere
  ingress {
    description = "SSH from VPC"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "allow_web"
  }
}

########Net Interface for the Instance########
#resource "aws_network_interface" "wsn" {
#  subnet_id       = aws_subnet.subnet1.id
#  private_ips     = ["10.0.1.50"]
#  security_groups = [aws_security_group.sec1.id]
#}

########Load Balancer########
resource "aws_elb" "elb" {
    name = "lb"
    subnets = [aws_subnet.subnet1.id]
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.sec1.id]
    instances = [aws_instance.web1.id]

    listener {
        instance_port = 80
        instance_protocol = "http"
        lb_port = 80
        lb_protocol = "http"


    }

}

########EC2 Instance########
resource "aws_instance" "web1" {
    ami             = "ami-003634241a8fcdec0" #ubuntu 18.4
    instance_type   = "t2.micro"
    availability_zone = "us-west-2a"
    key_name = "main-key"
    subnet_id = aws_subnet.subnet1.id

    #network_interface {
    #        device_index = 0
    #        network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.wsn.id
    #}

    user_data = <<-EOF
        #!/bin/bash
        sudo apt update -y
        sudo apt install apache2 -y
        sudo systemctl start apache2
        sudo bash -c 'echo Hello world!!! > /var/www/html/index.html'

        
        EOF



    tags = {
    Name = "HelloWorld"
  }
}

output "aws_elb_public_dns" {
    value = aws_elb.elb.dns_name

}
```

The plan and the apply runs all fine but in the loadbalancer the instance is "outofservice"
what could be wrong here??

Comment: In the future, please consider sanitizing your post for personal credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **missing security group** to your instance: [vpc_security_group_ids](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#vpc_security_group_ids).

Subsequently, you won't be able to ssh to it nor the http traffic will be allowed from the outside.

Also your **route  to IGW is incorrect**. It should be:

```
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
```

Same for SG for your ELB to allow traffic from the internet. It should be:

```
 cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
```

Comment: Thanks buddy I did your changes and also created a separate SG with:
`ingress {
        from_port = 80
        to_port = 80
        protocol = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["10.1.0.0/16"]
    }`
for the EC2 instances and now it's working fine.